# ggplot on the basis of time interval in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, gis

I have produced a ggplot of a GIS data based on Lat & Long. Time in this data frame is sometimes continuous and sometimes not, such as:

```
 Date  Time  Lat  Lon
1-1-08 23.00  12   13
1-1-08 23.20  14   18
1-1-08 23.50  20   14
2-1-08 00.00  16   17
2-1-08 00.30  13   20
2-1-08 00.50  18   19
2-1-08 01.30  11   21
2-1-08 01.40  15   18
2-1-08 01.50  16   13
2-1-08 01.00  17   13
2-1-08 01.10  10   15
....
```

I have initially used ggplot for Latitude and Longitude. But now I am getting problem in adding time interval in the plot.

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=Lat, x=Long)) + geom_point() + geom_path()
```

I want to add zoom in and zoom out effects in my plot on the basis of time interval.

Time interval here refers to the details of the plot. Such as: lesser the time interval highly detailed the plot should be and vice versa [in other case it skips some data to plot based on time interval selected].

Can anyone help me in this? Is this possible with ggplot to have the zoom effect? If not can you suggest some other solution to it?

Comment: what's the time interval referring to? lat - longs?

Comment: @Fairy yes, what i mean is I want to plot like: if i have a time interval of 20 mins, or 30 mins or 1 hr. or so... then the plot should change accordingly showing the points after every 20 mins or 30 mins interval and so on...